# Three20 TTTableViewController load more automatically

Tags: ios, three20

I've a TTTableViewController which follows TTTableViewController -> TTDataSource -> TTModel pattern. I've TTTableMoreButton and my list goes on to load more items when the user clicks on it.

How can I change the behaviour of this TTTableMoreButton? When the user came to the end of the list, I want it to behave as if it is clicked. In Facebook app, there is an implementation like this. I hope I could tell what I want.

Comment: I've just found and implemented the solution and I can share it if anyone wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://code.coneybeare.net/three20-how-to-autoload-more-results-when-you) is how to do it.

*full disclosure:* It is my code blog.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've also added my own implementation. It works perfectly but if there is a mistake (e.g. about the performance), let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

Here I've my own approach which i found out just before coneybeare's answer. I simply subclassed TTTableMoreButton and TTTableMoreButtonCell classes and in the "- (void)layoutSubviews" method, I detect that "Load More" button is appearing, and it should start loading more data if it is not already doing it.

I'm not sure which approach (coneybeaare's or mine) is the best and I'm looking forward for the comments about it.

AutoMoreTableItem.h

```
@interface AutoMoreTableItem : TTTableMoreButton {

}

@end
```

AutoMoreTableItem.m

```
#import "AutoMoreTableItem.h"

@implementation AutoMoreTableItem

@end
```

AutoMoreTableItemCell.h

```
@interface AutoMoreTableItemCell : TTTableMoreButtonCell {

}

@end
```

AutoMoreTableItemCell.m

```
#import "AutoMoreTableItemCell.h"
#import "AutoMoreTableItem.h"


@implementation AutoMoreTableItemCell
- (void)setObject:(id)object {
    if (_item != object) {
        [super setObject:object];

        AutoMoreTableItem* item = object;
        self.animating = item.isLoading;

        self.textLabel.textColor = TTSTYLEVAR(moreLinkTextColor);
        self.selectionStyle = TTSTYLEVAR(tableSelectionStyle);
        self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}


- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    AutoMoreTableItem* moreLink = self.object;
    if(moreLink.isLoading ==YES) {
        return;
    }

    if (moreLink.model) {
        moreLink.isLoading = YES;
        self.animating = YES;
        [moreLink.model load:TTURLRequestCachePolicyDefault more:YES];

    }

}

@end
```

And of course, in the datasource implementation:

```
- (Class)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellClassForObject:(id) object {   

    if([object isKindOfClass:[AutoMoreTableItem class]]){
        return [AutoMoreTableItemCell class];  
    }  else {  
        return [super tableView:tableView cellClassForObject:object];  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Congrats on solving yourself, but I feel that the logic to load more cells should not be contained within the cell itself, but in the controller/data_source layer. It is closer to MVC

Comment: Just used a subtle variant of your code, thanks :), btw, `AutoMoreTableItem` is not really needed since I guess you have no other use of `TTTableMoreButton`, also I preferred `willMoveToSuperview` to call `load:more:`. Also your `setObject` override doing the same as `super`: it is useless, and worse, does somethings already done by calling `[super setObject:object]`.